# How to input control A (^A) delimited input in Rest

Tags: java, spring, rest, delimiter

I want to take input which should be control A delimited in Rest
Currently I take input which is comma separated.

How to do that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried any code?

Please do some research (like searching in google) before asking here. for more help, see the [ask] page.

Comment: What I found is ^A, but is that correct